# Не получается отправить запрос к API

Tags: php, guzzle

Вообщем вот в чем дело, мне нужно подключиться к API Мой склад. Мне посоветовали для подключения воспользоваться библиотекой GuzzleHttp. Я установил эту библиотеку и попробовал подключаться к другим API , например openweather и все работало. И когда я уже перешел к подключению API Мой склад
появилась проблема. А именно в браузере пишет Страница недоступна HTTP ERROR 500 и в консоли

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()
> и crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.

Вот мой код

```
<?php 

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
 
    //'base_uri' => 'https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.2/security/token', // базовый uri
    //'Authorization' => "Basic " . base64_encode("inter".':'."qwe-asd")


$client = new Client([
    'base_uri' => 'https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.2/security/token',
    'timeout' => 2.0
]);
$params = [
  'Authorization' => "Basic" . base64_encode("login".':'."pass")
];
$response = $client ->request('GET',$params); //POST тоже пробовал


echo $response-> getStatusCode(),"<br>";

$body = $response-> getBody();

echo $body->getContents(),"<br>";



echo "<pre>";
print_r($response);
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я не так делаю. Буду очень благодарен.
Подключаться пробовал по лог:пароль и по токену.

php error

> [01-Dec-2021 16:51:49 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught >InvalidArgumentException: URI must be a string or UriInterface in >D:\Programs\MAMP\htdocs\vendor\guzzlehttp\psr7\src\Utils.php:426
> Stack trace:
> #0 D:\Programs\MAMP\htdocs\vendor\guzzlehttp\psr7\src\functions.php(41): >GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Utils::uriFor(Array)
> #1 D:\Programs\MAMP\htdocs\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Client.php(154): >GuzzleHttp\Psr7\uri_for(Array)
> #2 D:\Programs\MAMP\htdocs\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Client.php(181): >GuzzleHttp\Client->requestAsync('GET', Array, Array)
> #3 D:\Programs\MAMP\htdocs\sklad.php(17): GuzzleHttp\Client->request('GET', >Array)
> #4 {main}
> thrown in D:\Programs\MAMP\htdocs\vendor\guzzlehttp\psr7\src\Utils.php on >line 426

Comment: смотрите логи сервера. Ошибка 500 может быть по многим причинам, нужна конкретная

Comment: Я добавил к вопросу логи php error. Тут что-то связанное с URI

Comment: `$response = $client ->request('GET',$params);` ошибка здесь. Посмотрите в документации аргументы метода, что и в какой последовательности идёт

Comment: @ArchDemon дело в том, что в документации указанно именно так делать.

Comment: @Only091 Да неужели? Полистайте примеры [Quick Start](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html). `request` принимает 3 параметра, два первых -- строка, третий -- массив. Вы передаете массив вторым параметром, в ошибке Вам прямо пишут что `URI must be a string or UriInterface`, речь о втором параметре.

Comment: А что мне вторым параметром передавать? Если мне нужно только отправить логин и пароль?

Comment: @Simon Делал с другим примером, передавал так же 2 параметра, только второй был не массивом, все работало, тут если я массив переделаю в обычную строку будет такая же ошибка.
Не могу понять что не так...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы извините, но проблема высосана из пальца. Я понимаю что Вам нужно передать только логин и пароль. Здесь не так, как раз то, что вторым параметром должна быть все равно строка, так уж написано и так это работает и не так именно то, что Вы передаете массив вместо строки, как я уже и писал.

Можно же все привести к нормальному виду, `base_uri` на то и `base`, в документации же написано: Базовый URI клиента, объединенный в относительные URI. Может быть строкой или экземпляром UriInterface. Когда относительный URI предоставляется клиенту, клиент объединяет базовый URI с относительным URI. Следственно можно скорректировать Ваш код таким образом, чтобы сделать его более универсальным и иметь возможность отправлять запросы на разные эндпойнты:

```
$client = new Client([
    'base_uri' => 'https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.2/',
    'timeout' => 2.0
]);

$params = [
  'auth' => ['login', 'pass']
];

$response = $client->request('POST', '/security/token', $params);
```

и это решит Вашу проблему. Согласно [документации мой склад](https://dev.moysklad.ru/doc/api/remap/1.2/#mojsklad-json-api-obschie-swedeniq-autentifikaciq), это должен быть `POST` запрос

И Authorization параметры можно передать иначе [документация](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#auth).

Comment: Спасибо большое, стало хотя бы работать, но приходит ответ не такой как указан в документации.

Comment: Извиняюсь за еще один глупый вопрос.... Я пытаюсь получить ответ от API getBody()->getContents() и мне почему то приходят html страницы сайта мой склад а должен прийти токен... не подскажите в чем проблема?

Comment: @Only091 лучше задайте отдельным вопросом и приведите сам код и ответ от сервера. Так будет проще понять что не так и дать какой-то конкретный ответ, да и в комментариях обсуждать такие вещи не слишком удобно, к тому же на вопрос обращу внимание не только я и будет больше шансов получить ответ.